# Update an array of objects with or without mutation dynamically

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, methods

I am currently working a todo list project using plain JavaScript and have to create a function that updates a projects title,description, priority, etc. Is there a way to update the array of objects with or without mutation ?
An example would be something along the lines of

```js
project1.tasks[2].title = newTitle
```

```js
// Project Manager object
const PM = {
    // Empty projects array
    projects: [],
    // Project method pushing to projects array
    addProject(project) {
        this.projects.push(project)
    },
    deleteProject(project) {
        const projectIndex = this.projects.indexOf(project)
        if (projectIndex !== -1) {
            this.projects.splice(projectIndex, 1)
            return true
        }
        return false
    },
    updateProject() {
        // Update projects title, description, priority
    }
}
```

```js
const projectFactory = (title) => ({
    title,
    tasks: [],
    addTask(task) {
        this.tasks.push(task)
    },
    deleteTask(task) {
        const taskIndex = this.tasks.indexOf(task)
        if (taskIndex !== -1) {
            this.tasks.splice(taskIndex, 1)
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
})
```

```js
const createProject = (title) => {
    const project = projectFactory(title)
    return project
}
```

```js
const taskFactory = (title, description, dueDate, priority) => ({ title, description, dueDate, priority })

const createTask = (title, description, dueDate, priority) => {
    const task = taskFactory(title, description, dueDate, priority)
    return task`
}
```

```js
const project1 = projectFactory("Clean")
const task1 = taskFactory("Clean kitchen", "Wash dishes", "1/19/2023", "Medium")

PM.addProject(project1)
project1.addTask(task1)



I have tried to follow along on similiar problems that people have come across on StackOverflow but they're using ids or their todo list is made in React.
```

Comment: You give an example; does it not work? I'm not sure what you are actually asking.

Comment: I would like to update/edit each project after it has been created. For example say I have a object which is a project const project1 = projectFactory("Clean") and in that project I have tasks, const task1 = taskFactory("Clean kitchen", "Wash dishes", "1/19/2023", "Medium"). How would one create a function that can update the project title or the tasks within the project dynamically.